# Python: measuring the memory consumption of functions

Tags: python, memory, psutil

I know that there are already a lot of questions about this topic but I cannot find something that satisfies me.
I am looking for a way to log the memory consumption of my functions in python.
The ideal would be to measure the maximum of memory occupied by the process during each function execution and store it.
The objective is to have a log file storing the execution of several functions at a given date with the memory they consummed.

The code I am working on is supposed to be deployed so I would like to avoid special command prompts like `mprof` from the `memory-profiler`.

I would like to be able to wrap it around a function without modifying its code so I cannot use `psutil` functions such as `Process.memory_info` since it seems to give real-time informations and the `peak_wset` argument is not reset so if a function executed before consummed a lot of memory, it will falsify the result.

Finally I tried the module `tracemalloc` which seemed to work perfectly, except I cannot measure the consumption for nested functions. Here is a simple sample of code I tried:

```
import tracemalloc
from typing import Callable
import numpy as np

import psutil

d: dict[str, dict[str, tuple]] = {}


def memory_mesure(func: Callable):
    def memory_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        tracemalloc.start()
        s = psutil.Process().memory_info()
        key = f"{func.__name__}_{len(d)}"
        d[key] = {}
        d[key]["start"] = (s.rss, s.vms, s.peak_wset)
        # d[key]["start"] = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        e = psutil.Process().memory_info()
        d[key]["end"] = (e.rss, e.vms, e.peak_wset)
        # d[key]["end"] = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
        # tracemalloc.stop()

    return memory_wrapper


@memory_mesure
def f(i):
    r = {}
    r[0] = np.zeros((i,))
    del r[0]
    r[1] = np.zeros((i,))
    del r[1]


@memory_mesure
def g():
    f(1000000000)
    f(100000)


g()
```

The result given by `psutil` are the following:

```
g_0
    start - (31166464, 257990656, 31166464)
    end - (31170560, 257990656, 31174656)
    => (4096, 0, 8192)
f_1
    start - (31170560, 257990656, 31170560)
    end - (31170560, 257990656, 31174656)
    => (0, 0, 4096)
f_2
    start - (31170560, 257990656, 31174656)
    end - (31170560, 257990656, 31174656)
    => (0, 0, 0)
```

which is not satisfying since the values for `rss` and `vms` are the same before and after the executions of the `f` function hence the difference is 0. Moreover, since the process is not reset, the `peak_wset` did not change before and after the 2nd execution of `f`.

The results are similar when I use `tracemalloc` whithout the `tracemalloc.stop()` line at the end of the wrapper, and they does not seem to have any signification when I add this line, which seems logical. I suppose the first call to `tracemalloc.start()` launches a measure process which is not influenced by the other calls to `tracemalloc.start()` and so it does not seem possible to use this library for the objective I have.

The results I expect for this code are:

- a strictly positive value for `g_0`, `f_1` and `f_2`
- the value for `f_1` being strictly superior than the value for `f_2` since we build a much larger array
- the value for `g_0` being superior to both values for `f_1` and `f_2` since the `g_0` execution contains the execution of the two `f` functions.

Comment: For most allocations, Python does not return the memory back to the operating system when it is does with the allocation. (Larger allocations use mmap, which is returned when Python is done with it.) Measuring OS-level memory usage is not going to be very accurate for long programs, it will just tell you the peak memory use.

Comment: @NickODell so you think what I am trying to do is pointless ? My objective is to be able to determine if a call to a function is taking a very large amount of memory.

Comment: No, I'm just saying that some tools can't give you what you want. `psutil.Process().memory_info()` is an OS-level measurement. Any OS-level measurement cannot tell the difference between memory which is committed to your process but not used and memory which is committed to your process but used. Tracemalloc can, though.

Comment: OK thanks for this indications @NickODell.
But I still cannot use tracemalloc